# PostgresSQL/SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the activity_id of the row of every first "email" activity that happened in between the "completed_order" activity in a column "first_in_between"
I wrote this query

```
SELECT  activity_id, customer , activity, ts,
case 
        when 
         activity = 'completed_order' and lead(activity) over (partition by customer order by ts) ='email'
        then        
      lead(activity_id) over (partition by customer order by ts)
    end as First_in_between
    
    from activity_stream where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand'
        order by ts
```

With the above Query, I am getting this result.

[image: Screenshot of the above Query]

My Desired Results should be

[image: Scrrenshot of the Desired Result]

Comment: lead activity of 10343 is not email so its displaying 'null' right?  how/why you expect 11091 in desired results?

Comment: Yes,  I couldn't apply the correct logic to get only the ID of the first "email" between the "completed_order" activity.

Comment: Please embed screenshots in your post and remove links. It makes the question more readable

Comment: I tried to post the screenshot, but it didn't let me so I attached the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can readily get the *timestamp* of the email using:

```
select activity_id, customer , activity, ts,
       (case when activity = 'completed_order' and
                  (min(ts) filter (where activity = 'email') over (partition by customer order by ts desc) <
                   min(ts) filter (where activity = 'completed_order') over (partition by customer order by ts desc)
                  )
             then min(ts) filter (where activity = 'email') over (partition by customer order by ts desc)
        end) as First_in_between    
from activity_stream
where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand'
order by ts;
```

You can then join back to the table or use another level of window functions to get the corresponding `activity_id` for the timestamp.

Actually, I think I prefer another method, which is just to count the number of completed orders and then take the minimum ts:

```
select a.*,
       min(ts) filter (where activity = 'email') over (partition by grp) as email_ts
from (select a.*,
             count(*) filter (where activity = 'completed_order') over (partition by customer order by ts) as grp
      from activity_stream a
      where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand'
     ) a;
```

This should also allow you to use a twist to get the activity id without an additional subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (array_agg(activity_id order by ts) filter (where activity = 'email') over (partition by grp))[1] as email_activity_id
from (select a.*,
             count(*) filter (where activity = 'completed_order') over (partition by grp order by ts) as grp
      from activity_stream a
      where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand'
     ) a
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. The first query returns the null output. so if you can guide me on how to get the activity_id that would be great.  also, it is necessary the code should not be a  CTE code.
And the second and third query gives me an error.

Comment: @AnsaDhedhi . . . Oops, the second and third should have used window functions.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: Hey, I am getting only the min ts of first_email. I think we will have to try something else. Can you guide me?